# typedef changing value names with different type names

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

If I have:

```
typedef struct Foo {
    int x, y;
} Point, SomethingElse;
```

and I want `Foo.x` to equal `Point.x` but I want `SomethingElse.a` to also be equal to `Point.x` or in other words, I want `SomethingElse` to be the exact same as `Foo` and `Point` but with its two variables named other things. It would seem like a waste if I have to make a whole new struct.

Comment: You should have two structs IMHO. Or add a third variable called a. But to be honest I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Any sample code?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I have an essentially identical setup to what is in the question except something else is a vector (the magnitude / direction kind) and it's confusing to use x and y, and making a struct feels wrong EDIT: oh and also they are floats but that shouldn't matter

Comment: I will be interested with what people come up with. If the variables are different types and names I can not see how you can do it.

Comment: you can probably cast to union (which is allowed for commoninitial sequence of standard layout type) although that is a terrible idea really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instead treat the variables as an array within the object and use the array operator to retrieve the values using variables with the names you desire.

```
struct example{
  int data[2];
  int& operator[](int index){
    //range check index before lookup if desired
    return data[index];
  }
};

int X=0;
int Y=1;
int A=0;
int B=1;

typedef example Point;
typedef example SomethingElse;


int main(int argc,char** argv){
  Point p;
  SomethingElse s;

  p[X]=0;

  s[A]=0;


  return 0;
}
```

This is one way you could do something like what you are requesting, but I would suggest either declaring unique structs with the names you desire in each one rather than trying to provide aliases to names of variables within a struct. It seems like much less of a headache to just declare a second struct.

Comment: I agree. Make a second structure!

Answer (score 2):

If enforcing the different variable names for the different types isn't a requirement, what about using unions?

```
typedef struct Foo
{
    union
    {
        int a;
        int x;
    };
    union
    {
        int b;
        int y;
    };
} Point, SomethingElse;
```

Comment: This could possibly lead to undefined behavior if the user were to write to x then read from a. I don't remember exactly what the standard says in this case since a & x are of the same type, but my understanding is that is undefined behavior to write to one variable within a union and read from another. This assumes someone will do this of course, but the design does leave the possibility

Comment: this is UB in ISO C++  (there is an exception for unions to share a struct with common initial sequence, but `int a` is not a struct)

Comment: this works great, I forgot unions even existed! but is there any way I can prevent people from doing `Point.a` and `SomethingElse.x`?

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 different typdefs which are identiacal structs declared in one statment. `SomethingElse` doesn't have a member named `a`.

Also maybe you wanted a `typedef union`?